# Can't connect to Azure SQL by guested user via Azure AD auth

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-active-directory

I created db in Azure SQL and configured Azure auth, thus I can connect to db via SQL Management Studio using my Azure AD account. Then I added user from other Azure AD and when I execute `CREATE USER [user@mytenant1.onmicrosoft.com] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER` I get error

> Principal 'user@mytenant1.onmicrosoft.com' could not be found or this principal type is not supported.

This user `user@mytenant1.onmicrosoft.com` is in my Azure AD as invited guest user.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So finally I got it worked. The reason was that **invited use have to accept invitation**. Since I invited user without real email I(or some person) had to "click" invitation link somehow. I did it via PowerShell.

These steps need to be done to grant read access for guested user:

1. Install Azure Ad module. I did it via command `Install-Module AzureAd`
2. Connect to AAD you are going to invite user via `Connect-AzureAD`
3. Invite user to AAD via command `New-AzureADMSInvitation -InvitedUserEmailAddress "<user_email>" -InviteRedirectUrl "https://portal.azure.com" -SendInvitationMessage $false -InvitedUserType "Guest"`. Where **< user_email>** the email of inviting user. The result of this command will be object with attributes, one of them - invitation link.
   [image]
   ***NOTE: Copy it in notepad first and format it, copy then in browser and accept invitation, or send it to person who ownes this account.***
4. Now to add user to DB we have to execute T-SQL `CREATE USER [<user principal>] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER`. The trick is **< user principal >** for invited users has "EXT" format. To get right principal just execute `Get-AzureADUser` - this command lists users with real user principal names.

> Example:
>
> Real email: user1@dep1.myorg.com
>
> Principal name: user1_dep1.myorg.com#EXT#@targetazuread.onmicrosoft.com

Copy corresponding principal and run `CREATE USER...`

5. Last step, for my case, was grant new user read permissions, thus I called `EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', '<user principal>'`

   As result I can connect to db with invited user. Also I know where to see real user principal via `Get-AzureADUser` command of powershell (Azure AD module).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it directly, you have to use a group instead.
Create a group (i.e.test) in the main AAD and add the guest user there.
Next create in SQL DB a user (test) who is in the AAD group and connect to this DB using your guest user

Comment: Did you try this ? Does it work for you ? I just tried and it doesn't work neither. I created group `external_db`, invited guest user and add it to this group, added group to db with `CREATE USER [external_db] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER`, tried connected with guested user and got `Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)`. Then  I added native user in this group and it connected to db. To sum up: Azure AD auth is not applicable for external\guested users.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the user to the database as follows:

```
CREATE USER [your.user_example.com#EXT#@<yourAzureSubscriptionPrefix>.onmicrosoft.com] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER
```

You can also create a group in Azure Active Directory, add the external user to the group, then add the group to the database.

```
CREATE USER [GroupFromAzureActiveDirectory] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried with this weird syntax before and got the same error. Also I didn't find any official microsoft page with such syntax, thus it looks to me like a "hack".